# Excel convert date to text retaining date layout

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have rows containing every Monday and Sunday in an entire year, (with variations on when a month starts and ends) like so,

```
11/05/2015  18/05/2015  25/05/2015  01/06/2015  08/06/2015
17/05/2015  24/05/2015  31/05/2015  07/06/2015  14/06/2015
```

However these are in the date format, and I need them in a text format, but so they still read in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, not like `42125`.

Further up my document, each column header should read `dd/mm/yyyy-dd/mm/yyyy` using each of the dates shown in my first example, and I was hoping to achieve this using the formula `=A30&"-"&A31` and so on. So the desired outcome should read,

```
11/05/2015-17/05/2015   18/05/2015-24/05/2015

      11/05/2015            18/05/2015
      17/05/2015            24/05/2015
```

However using the `=cell&cell` formula im left with

```
42135-42141 42142-42148

11/05/2015  18/05/2015
17/05/2015  24/05/2015
```

I have to create these headings for 2 years worth of dates, and trying to avoid typing every heading out manually, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting those values to text before concatenating:

```
=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")&"-"&TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: All the other answers work too but this is exactly what I needed thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `TEXT` function which comes with Excel.

Assuming cell A1 has "11/05/2015", use the following formula in cell B1:

```
B1=TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

This takes care of the first part of your question.  For the second part, you can use the `CONCATENATE` function.  Assuming that B1 and B2 contain dates as text, you can join them together using the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1, "-", B2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to break them down like so:

```
=DAY(A3)&"/"&MONTH(A3)&"/"&YEAR(A3)&"-"&DAY(A4)&"/"&MONTH(A4)&"/"&YEAR(A4)
```

I am assuming here your data start from cell A3

Answer (score 2):

Assuming headings in row 1 and dates in rows 3 and 4 this will work:

`=TEXT(A3,"dd/mm/yyyy")&TEXT(A4," - dd/mm/yyyy")`

without having to concatenate `" - "`

Comment: Everyone gets 1 point today.  It's like Little League baseball where everyone gets a trophy :-)